# KendoUI Grid With Angular2 : Configure sorting in column template

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-grid

Is there any to configure column to allow sort or not with help of template column.

Grid has already set `[sortable]="true"`

I am **able** to configure in direct on column as below:

```
<kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let col of columns;"  field="{{col.Name}}" title="col.Name" [sortable]="col.CanSort">               
</kendo-grid-column>
```

But **not able** to configure with help of template as below:

```
<template *ngFor="let col of columns" let-column>                
     <kendo-grid-column field="{{col.Name}}" title="col.Name" [sortable]="false">
           <template kendoHeaderTemplate let-dataItem>
               {{dataItem.field}}            
           </template>
      </kendo-grid-column>                   
 </template>
```

Any one has idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got an answer:

we have to define column tag prior to the template one. You can also get checkbox column based on some condion as below.

```
<kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let col of columns"  field="{{col.Name}}" title="col.Name" [sortable]="col.CanSort" >
       <template kendoCellTemplate let-dataItem *ngIf="col.DataType=='Boolean'">
                <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem[col.Name]" disabled />
       </template>          
</kendo-grid-column>
```